# Universal camera control for multi platforms

Tags: winapi, opencv, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I need to adjust the parameters of the camera like 1) brightness 2) contrast 3) Hue etc., as show in the below window.

I need to do it for Windows and Linux environments.

Can some one give me tips on where to start. On googling I could found only few open-sources. But couldnt get an idea where to start.

I have also tried with "Camera calibration With OpenCV", but still is there any other libraries available for my purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you could try:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_SETTINGS,1);
```

to get to the settings dialogue

Comment: It's working..... I went thorugh the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) ... but the documentation of CAP_PROP_SETTINGS is not there... Can you point me the link where you referred the documentation of CAP_PROP_SETTINGS... Thanks

Comment: i don't think it's properly documentated, but you can find all those CV_CAP_* enum things in highgui.hpp, ~L300 ( btw, sorry for omitting the CV_ prefix above)

Comment: Thanks.. Just wanted to know where I can go through the detailed documentation of CV_CAP_*... I also have doubts regarding the range of values we can set in for example CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS ... If I set 100, it resets to zero. Can you point me to some reference???